# How to transfer characters between uppercase and lowercase with sed

Tags: sed, uppercase, lowercase

For example, my src.tex is

**SectionType *p = NULL;**

and I want it change to

**section_type *p = NULL;**

what I want to do is just change the **SectionType**, but remains the **NULL** unchanged, I used **y/[A-Z]/[a-z]**, but this will change all the line.

My sed do not support \L,\l,\U and \u functions, it version is 3.* and distributed under FSF, not GNU, may be GNU's works well with this functions, but at the time I could not adopt the GNU's because I'm working in msys and there is no GNU package.

Is there any solution to get it?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: Ah, I missed the no GNU part. Use Ignacio's link and the sed I posted and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.amirwatad.com/blog/archives/2009/05/30/convert-camelcase-to-underscores-using-sed/)

Convert CamelCase or camelCase to camel_case:

`sed -e 's/\([A-Z][a-z]\)/_\l\1/g' -e 's/^_\([a-z]\)/\1/g' file.txt`

Input:

```
SectionType *p = NULL;
sectionType *p = NULL;
ABCSectionType *p = NULL;
```

Output:

```
section_type *p = NULL;
section_type *p = NULL;
ABC_section_type *p = NULL;
```

Comment: hmm... this seems to trample the `NULL`. Looking for a solution. EDIT: fixed. added the `[a-z]` on the first expression to have it ignore things in all caps.

Comment: I tried your script in MSYS, but still can not work with my sed, because your script used a **\l** to tansfer the first character, and my sed do not support the function...

Comment: I download a GNU distribution of sed, name it as 'gsed', and put it under **MSYS/bin**, it works well with your script, and we can use **-i** to overwrite the file we got to transfer, save a lot of key-press under command line. :)  any way, we should test each version of sed to get our script run most of the time. Thanks for your advise. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it's working out for you. When you find the right answer to your questions on stackoverflow, you should mark the answer as the accepted answer (click the check box next to the answer).

Answer (score 1):

This should work without having to install another version of `sed`. It changes the case only on the first word of the line.

```
upper=$(printf "%s" {A..Z})
lower=$(printf "%s" {a..z})
sed "s/ /\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n//;x;s/\n.*//;y/$upper/$lower/;G;s/\n//" inputfile
```

My version of `sed` won't do `y/[A-Z]/[a-z]/`, it needs each character explicitly included which is why I used the variables. The way I created them depends on a feature that only some shells, such as Bash and ksh, have. You can do a simple assignment or use the range if your `sed` supports it.

If your version of `sed` is really picky, it may want `-e` instead of semicolons. This version should work in that case:

```
sed -e "s/ /\n/" -e "h" -e "s/[^\n]*\n//" -e "x" -e "s/\n.*//" -e "y/$upper/$lower/" -e "G" -e "s/\n//" inputfile
```

Comment: Currently, I do not know these advanced features of sed, with only 3 days learning, I just got some regular expression and replacement syntax used in sed... but your code looks wonderful, and I really test it in my sed, as your said, runs well, and... to hard to type so many characters without **ctrl + c/v**.. :)