# sed: replace CamelCase by Camel:Case

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to insert a colon everywhere a **lowercase** letter is followed by an **uppercase** letter, and add characters around the first word: (from `CamelCase` to `<Camel>:Case`)

This is my best shot, based on: [How to transfer characters between uppercase and lowercase with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130205/how-to-transfer-characters-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-with-sed)

```
echo CamelCase | sed -e 's/\([a-z][A-Z]\)/\1:/g'

CamelC:ase
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `sed`:

```
echo 'CamelCase' | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1:\2/g'
Camel:Case
```

#### UPDATE: As per comments:

```
echo 'CamelCase' | sed -e 's/\([A-Z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z]\)/<\1>:\2/g'
<Camel>:Case
```

Comment: Great, but what if I want to colorize the word preceding the colon? "`'s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\'${g}'\1:\'${x}'\2/g'`" only affects the last letter before the colon... (`g='\e[0;32m'  x='\e[0m'`)

Comment: For colorizing I think escape sequences need to be used and that highly terminal dependent. Sorry I don't remember those color codes myself.

Comment: Also may I request you to create a separate question for colorizing problem to get better answers. Let this being the camel case problem.

Comment: The color codes are fine. The problem is the REGEX, which fails to match the first word. In other words, how can I get from `CamelCase` to `_Camel_:Case`?

Comment: ok that command would be: `echo 'CamelCase' | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1:\2/g' -e 's/\([^:]*\):/_\1_:/'`